# Solve $2x^2+xy-2y^2=-2 , \,x^2-3xy-5y^2=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve $$2x^2+xy-2y^2=-2\quad \& \quad x^2-3xy-5y^2=5$$

I've tried completing the square and that went really confusing quickly. Any handy tips on how to tackle questions like these? Cause I have a bunch more

Comment: So completing the square is one way, you could use quadratic formula as well to get one variable in terms of the other, then plug into the other equation.

Comment: mostly look first for integer points. Each hyperbola has some.

Comment: and draw some pictures on graph paper. Actual paper...

Comment: First avoid mixed factor $xy$, express one variable and insert back into one of the equations.

Answer (score 2):

First try would be to get rid of the constants.  Multiply the first equation by $5$, the second one by $2$ and add to get
$$12x^2-xy-20y^2=0\iff(3x-4y)(4x+5y)=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, using the quadratic formula on the first one yields:

$$x=\frac{-\text{y}\pm\sqrt{\text{y}^2-4\cdot2\cdot\left(2-2\text{y}^2\right)}}{2\cdot2}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{17\text{y}^2-16}-\text{y}}{4}\tag1$$

Using the quadratic formula on the second one yields:

$$x=\frac{-\left(-3\text{y}\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(-3\text{y}\right)^2-4\cdot1\cdot\left(-5-5\text{y}^2\right)}}{2\cdot1}=\frac{3\text{y}\pm\sqrt{29\text{y}^2+20}}{2}\tag2$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{\pm\sqrt{17\text{y}^2-16}-\text{y}}{4}=\frac{3\text{y}\pm\sqrt{29\text{y}^2+20}}{2}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\pm2\sqrt{17\text{y}^2-16}-2\text{y}=12\text{y}\pm4\sqrt{29\text{y}^2+20}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\pm2\sqrt{17\text{y}^2-16}=14\text{y}\pm4\sqrt{29\text{y}^2+20}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\pm\sqrt{17\text{y}^2-16}=7\text{y}\pm2\sqrt{29\text{y}^2+20}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$17\text{y}^2-16=80+165\text{y}^2\pm28\text{y}\sqrt{29\text{y}^2+20}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$17\text{y}^2-16-80-165\text{y}^2=\pm28\text{y}\sqrt{29\text{y}^2+20}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$-4\left(24+37\text{y}^2\right)=\pm28\text{y}\sqrt{29\text{y}^2+20}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$24+37\text{y}^2=\mp7\text{y}\sqrt{29\text{y}^2+20}\tag3$$

Now, what happends when you try $\text{y}=\pm4$?

Answer (score 0):

Subtract twice the second equation from the first to obtain

$$7xy+8y^2=-12$$

and multiply the second equation by $49y^2$ to obtain

$$(7xy)^2-21(7xy)y^2-249y^4=245y^2$$

Substituting $-12-8y^2$ for $7xy$ gives $(-12-8y^2)^2-21(-12-8y^2)y^2-245y^4=245y^2$, which simplifies to a quadratic in $Y=y^2$: $(8Y+12)^2+21(8Y+12)Y-245Y^2=245Y$, or

$$(64+168-245)Y^2+(192+252-245)Y+144=0$$

which becomes

$$13Y^2-199Y-144=0$$

or

$$(13Y+9)(Y-16)=0$$

We can ignore $y^2=-9/13$ as a possible (real) solution, leaving $y^2=16$, or $y=\pm4$.  From $x=-(12+8y^2)/(7y)$, we get two possible solutions:

$$(x,y)=(-5,4)\qquad\text{and}\qquad(x,y)=(5,-4)$$

Remark: The key thing, really, was to eliminate one of the variables, leaving a polynomial in the other variable. There are lots of ways of doing this; the approach I took here was to try to avoid using fractions or radicals for as long as possible. And in this case we got lucky in that the final results turn out to be integers.

Answer (score 0):

Individually, if the equations are in standard form, the quadratic formula solves them easily for $y$ in terms of $x$.

$$2x^2+xy-2y^2+2=0\\
\implies 2y^2-xy -2(x^2+1)=0 \\ 
\implies y=\frac{x \pm \sqrt{x^2 - 4(2)(-2x^2-2)}}{2\cdot2}
 =   \frac{x \pm \sqrt{17 x^2 + 16}}{4}
$$
with some integer solutions of
$(0,\pm1), (3,4), (5,-4), (32,-25),( in32,42)$
$$
x^2-3xy-5y^2-5=0\\
\implies 5y^2+3xy-(x^2+5)=0\\
 \implies y=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{9 x^2 - 4(1)(-x^2+5)}}{2\cdot5}
 =\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{29 x^2 - 100}}{10}$$

with some integer solution of
$(2,-1), (5,-4), (5,1), (17,4) (37,-31), (130,31)$

Now, if you need the combined solution, you can set the two
$y$-equations  equal to each other, eliminating $y$, so you can solve for $x$